# Inner Join on three tables linked by foreignkeys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL programming and have the following scenario.
I have three tables which are linked to each other as -

**ForceInstance**

```
ForceInstanceID (PK)
ForceID (FK to Force)
Description
CreatedBy
CreatedOn
```

**Force**

```
ForceID (PK)
ForceTypeID (FK to ForceType)
Description
CreatedBy
CreatedOn`
```

**ForceType**

```
ForceTypeID (PK)
Description
```

I want to make a join of the three tables, I tried this query -

```
Select * from ForceInstance FI inner join 
              Force F inner join
              ForceType FT
          on  FI.ForceID = F.ForceID
          and F.ForceTypeID = FT.ForceTypeID
```

but was unable to achieve anything. I am new to SQL and wanted to know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from ForceInstance FI 
inner join Force F on  FI.ForceID = F.ForceID
inner join ForceType FT on F.ForceTypeID = FT.ForceTypeID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      ForceInstance FI 
          INNER JOIN Force F 
              ON FI.ForceID = F.ForceID 
          INNER JOIN ForceType FT
              ON F.ForceTypeID = FT.ForceTypeID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select * from ForceInstance FI  join 
              Force F 
              on  FI.ForceID = F.ForceID
             JOIN ForceType FT           
               on F.ForceTypeID = FT.ForceTypeID
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.